# Regular expression numbers with dots and commas

Tags: regex

I would need a regular expression that treats numbers with dots and commas the same way. Commas should not be treated as thousand separators.

Example:
9.8
9,8

should return 9.8 both

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?|)$
```

Comment: Did you try anything before asking your question here?

Comment: so `2,22,333` is equivalent to `2.22.333`

Comment: Yes I tried this, but it doesn't work. ^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?|)$

Comment: By the way , which language so we can give specific example.

Comment: Most languages have functions for handling number localizations, are you sure you need regex for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?|)$` matches numbers that have exactly 2 decimals, if you want to match any number (1 or more) of decimals, use:

```
^(?:\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?|)$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
^(\d*[.,]?\d*)*$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/bE4iS3

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
$re = '/(,)/mx'; 
$str = '9.8 \n9,8'; 
$subst = '.'; 
preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var re = /(,)/gmx; 
var str = '9.8 \n9,8';
var subst = '.'; 
str.replace(re, subst);
```

**PYTHON**

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(,)', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
str = "9.8 \n9,8"
subst = "." 
re.sub(p, subst, str)
```